# Requirements to run own mail server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, exchange, email-server, sendmail

I have the idea of setting up "MS Exchange mail server" in windows and "Squirrel/sendmail/postfix mail server" or something in linux. I have some domain names publicly registered. I am using google hosted mail domain(paid) for sending and receving mails to one another.

One thing I don't understand is what I've to do to run own mail server to exchange mails GLOBALLY either in windows or linux.

I have registered domains and I want to know what are the requirements to run own mail server so that all the employees in my office access the mail server anywhere in the world and exchange mails one another. I think it's called an SMTP server, anybody could short-list the things/requirements to run my own SMTP mail server?

Thank you all!

Comment: I know most of you know well what I'm asking and could be answered easily by mail server operators in real time. Just needs attention...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a server located either in your office or some provider. Second you need to setup Active Directory, it can be running on the same server that will be running Exchange, however suggested it would be a different machine. Second an Exchange server needs to be installed and configured. Third, you need to configure an access to the server for the users, it's called RPC over HTTPS. In essence, all Outlook to Exchange communication within the organization usually happens over RPC, since your requirement is that users will be accessing the server from anywhere in the world, in order to properly securing communication HTTPS is used, which is the most convenient way of connecting without using VPN. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes answered most of my doubts, Is AD mandatory?. How about linux box?, may be ldap or nis instead Active Directory.

Comment: Although you would think that LDAP is ldap everywhere, in Microsoft's world it's not so. They state that without their own Active Directory, the Exchange will not be supported. That's that. My or the highway approach.